# Extract data from .txt file to populate .csv file with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

We provide a consolidated .csv file to a supplier each day, containing sales orders. Due to known changes in our infrastructure in Q4, we are losing the application that manages this consolidation and it needs to be somehow developed manually.

We receive orders from our tills in .txt files, but they actually look like .csv. Files look like this

```
OR,00000330,9217,,20170904,,
,AG147,,,3.25,,1
,AG161,,,2.69,,2
,AG001,,,2,,2
,AG004,,,2,,2
,AG005,,,1.9,,2
,AG008,,,1.9,,2
,AG009,,,1.9,,2
,AG010,,,2.03,,2
,AG011,,,1.9,,2
,AG012,,,1.9,,2
,AG013,,,2.35,,2
,AG014,,,2.35,,2
,AG015,,,2.35,,2
,AG016,,,2.11,,2
```

I need to extract from these files (not all files contain same data):

- 9217 - Unique store identifier
- 20170904 - Delivery date
- AGXXX - Product Code
- Last value - Product quantity

As you can see from the file, it doesn't get presented with headers or column names. So already I'm hitting some issues.

In terms of what the final .csv file needs to look like, here is an example. I've manually edited in the headers, as again, this file has no header information.

```
SiteCode    SiteName    Address2    Address3    County  PostCode    Contactno   ?   Product Quantity    ?   ProuctCode  TransactionDate DeliveryDate
7001    Site    10 Big Street   The Big Street  Co.County   XXX-XXX 123456  1840246 ABC123  4   77168   Chicken Stuffing WB 01/08/2017  03/08/2017
```

"?" headers denote columns I'm awaiting confirmation on what they are.

So obviously there is plenty in the csv not contained within the sales order.

- SiteCode - This is in the sales order
- SiteName - I'll know this, can I have code in a script that when SiteCode = X then Sitename = y?
- Address - I'll know this, can I have code in a script that when SiteCode = x, then Address lines = y?
- County - Same as above
- PostCode - Same as above
- Contactno - Same as above
- Column H unknown - Need to find out what this value is
- Product Code - Need to extract and populate from sales order
- Quantity - Need to extract and populate from sales order
- Column K unknown - Granted value is the same every line. Can I define the value to insert in this column for every row?
- ProductName - Not in sales file, but I know the names. Can I pull this from a DB via PowerShell or define it within the script? When ProductCode = X then - PRoductName = Y?
- TransactionDate - This is the date the order is raised. It's in the filename, can I extract from filename to populate column?
- DeliveryDate - This is in the sales order, on the first line

Would greatly appreciate help here guys. There are parts I have working but going mental trying to get data extraction working here.

Comment: Of course it is possible to lookup information differing between first line and following. But the only person identifying the source and meaning of that is you. [SO] isn't a script writing service, so who do you think will put more effort in your ask than you yourself?

Comment: Hi Lot, I'm clearly here asking a question because I do not know the answer. Don't really need condescension or explanations on how sites like this work, I contribute plenty to many.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially it looks like you have a bunch of files with comma-delimited values (but not actual CSV, since the data in the first row is not the header and is also different from the rest of the data), and want to export that as a TSV (tab-separated values) file.

Since your input data is not really CSV I wouldn't bother with `Import-Csv`. Just read the file as text and split the rows.

```
$data = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt'

$store, $date = (($data | Select-Object -First 1) -split ',')[2, 4]

$data | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
    $product, $qty = ($_ -split ',')[1, -1]
    ...
}
```

Lookups of one value by another value are usually done via hashtables in PowerShell:

```
$sites = @{
    'foo' = 'Site A'
    'bar' = 'Site B'
    ...
}
$sitecode = 'bar'

$sites[$sitecode]    # returns 'Site B'
```

The values of the hashtable don't need to be simple strings, you can also have have nested hashtables, arrays or other objects there. For example a hashtable for looking up address data could look like this:

```
$addresses = @{
    'foo' = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Address' = 'Runaway Avenue 23'
        'Country' = 'Greenland'
        'Postcode' = 12345
        ...
    }
    'bar' = New-Object  -Type PSObject -Property @{
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Construct custom objects from your input data and the hashtables:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'SiteCode' = $sitecode
    'SiteName' = $sites[$sitecode]
    'Address2' = $addresses[$sitecode].Address
    'Postcode' = $addresses[$sitecode].Postcode
    ...
    'Quantity' = $qty
    ...
}
```

and export the generated objects to a TSV file via `Export-Csv`:

```
... | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType -Delimiter "`t"
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. Yeah I was starting off by converting the .txt into .csv with a script and then I was adding in headers manually but I think I went down a hole I couldn't get back out from. I've heard of Hashtables but havn't used them in any depth. I might look into them in more detail, that sounds like what I've been looking for. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is unethical to ask for an entire script that does what you want. So here is what will get you going.

When I copy that example data to a file, say, data.txt and read it into a variable

```
$Data = get-content C:\Data.txt
```

This is the pattern I notice
`$Data[0]` is the first line containing Unique Store Identifier and Delivery Date
So `$UniqueStoreId = $data[0].Split(",")[2]` and

```
$DeliveryDate = ([datetime]::ParseExact($data[0].Split(",")[4],”yyyyMMdd”,$null)).toshortdatestring()
```

Then, if the total number of lines `$Total = $data.Count`

Iterate through each line in a for loop as below. you will have everything you need like this.

```
For ($I=1; $I -lt $Total; $I++)
{
    $ProductCode = $Data[$I].Split(",")[1]
    $Quantity = $Data[$I].Split(",")[6]
}
```

Creating a custom CSV file is easy. Create a new PSObject and add the headers you need as its Property. Doing an `Export-CSV` on this will deliver the result in a perfect csv.

```
$CSVobject = [PSCustomObject] @{
        Header1 = $null
        Header2 = $null
        Header3 = $null
        #and so on
    }
```

Inside the for-loop itself, add the data you extract to the CSVObject like

```
$CSVObject.Header1 = "xxxx"
$CSVObject.Header2 = "yyyy"
```

Run this whole thing in loops or however you want to get the final CSV. below is a rough example

```
$FinalCSV = For ($I=1; $I -lt $Total; $I++)
{
    $ProductCode = $Data[$I].Split(",")[1]
    $Quantity = $Data[$I].Split(",")[6]

    $CSVobject.Header1 = $ProductCode
    $CSVObject.Heade2 = "$Quantity"

    $CSVObject
}
```

At the end, do `Export-CSV` to get the output you want.

Comment: Thanks Rohin. I'm aware how collaborative/community based platforms like this work. I'm not looking for anyone to do the work for me, I'm just struggling badly working with data that doesn't have headers, and also been unable to find information how to "cherry pick" what I want from one file to populate in another. As you say, you have got me going so thank you.